# How to Delineate All Index Entries Under a Heading Horizontally as a Paragraph

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, indexing, paragraphs, imakeidx

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\Large

Some words.\index{Heading@\textbf{Heading}! 1. This is the first index entry.}
\newpage Some more words.\index{Heading@\textbf{Heading}! 2. This is the second index entry.}
\newpage Some more words.\index{Heading@\textbf{Heading}! 3. This is the third index entry.}\index{Heading@\textbf{Heading}! 4. This is the fourth index entry.}
\newpage Some more words.\index{Heading@\textbf{Heading}! 5. This is the fifth index entry; Moreover, I would like all of these five entries to appear within a single paragraph under the heading with the same indentation as displayed.}
\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

which produces the index:

[image]

QUESTION: How may I horizontally list all of the index entries under a given heading as a paragraph instead of the usual vertical which as shown? I compile the code with `lualatex`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want?

[image: a]

Use `\usepackage[itemlayout= singlepar]{idxlayout}`

Comment: Many thanks Simon Dispa for your help, once again.