# How to Prevent Idxlayout's Placement of a Semicolon within the Content of an Index Entry for Paragraph-Type Delineations

Tags: luatex, indexing, paragraphs, imakeidx, idxlayout

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}
%\usepackage[itemlayout=singlepar]{idxlayout}

\begin{document}
\Large

Some words.\index{Examples@\textbf{Examples} quoted:! Example1}\index{Examples@\textbf{Examples} quoted:! Example2}\index{Examples@\textbf{Examples} quoted:! Example3}

\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

which produces the Index output

[image]

Now, if I replace the command `\usepackage{idxlayout}` with `\usepackage[itemlayout=singlepar]{idxlayout}` to produce horizontally delineated index entries, I get

[image]

QUESTION: Why is `Idxlayout` inserting a semicolon immediately after ``quoted:'' in the MWE? Is there a way to avoid having a semicolon placed after something that lies within the content of an index entry? I am hoping, in the case of horizontally listed index entries, to have a semicolon placed after page numbers only. (I compiled the code with `lualatex`.)

Thank you.

Comment: if I run your exampl (ither form) I get no output: tex reports: `No pages of output.`

Comment: @David Carlisle It comes from the answer given in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/637330/how-to-delineate-all-index-entries-under-a-heading-horizontally-as-a-paragraph

Comment: No, it doesn't that answer produces output. This one does not. At least it doesn't with `LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1` what are you using?

Comment: the; is being placed after the `\item` level entry  just as it is placed after `\subitem` which sems quite natural (it is puting the punctuation in the entry that makes it seem odd)

Comment: @David Carlisle Perhaps the problem is the shortcut that I tried to take with the MWE---Index entries without prior words; in which case, I just discovered that modifications to the Index commands are not accepted. I have modified the MWE to alleviate that problem. Sorry for the confusion.